# On Keyup action for multiple tr's and td's

Tags: jquery

Problem: I need access using the on keyup Jquery function on every row of a table.

I have multiple tables I need to do this for, but for now I'm starting with one. Driving by user selections info that drives that number of rows in the table. So it could 1 or could be up to 15. I need to multiply two inputs and output that to a td on the same row. The on keyup fires when the last td multiplied in the row is chosen.

I've been able to get it working on the first row, but no rows after work. The two td's stay the same in all tables. I've tried a few different ways of isolating the tr's with no success.

Here's the function I've been working with:

```
//The td location I want to output to
<td>
  <span id="mcalPremium">$</span>
</td>

 $("#alSublineValSubmitTBL tbody tr td:nth-child(11) input").on('keyup', function (e) {
    var ex = $("#alSublineValSubmitTBL tbody tr td:nth-child(11) input").val();
    var r = $("#alSublineValSubmitTBL tbody tr td:nth-child(9) input").val();
    var exp = parseInt(ex);
    var rate = parseFloat(r);
    var premium = rate * exp;

    //display premium in premium field
    //#mcalPremium is a span within the table. It is the precise location I want to display the multiplied number.

    $('#mcalPremium').html('$' + premium).digits();

});

 //Insert comma every for premium
    $.fn.digits = function () {
        return this.each(function () {
            $(this).text($(this).text().replace(/(\d)(?=(\d\d\d)+(?!\d))/g, "$1,"));
        });
    };
```

As always your help is greatly appreciated.

[image]

Comment: Why is the `$.fn.digits` being defined inside of the keyup event listener?

Comment: @CarstenLøvboAndersen After trying that it works, but it only does for the first row. Meaning the on keyup for the second and third table rows fires for the td in the first row

Comment: so use `this` to get the reference of the textbox and use that to get the 9th td

Comment: @epascarello I hadn't tried using outside of the listener. I just did and I see why you asked. I'll edit my question to show it sits out the listener.

Comment: No clue what  $('#mcalPremium') is, it is in the same row? is it one element? Showing some HTML will make it easier to answer.

Comment: @epascarello I added some info for you to see. $('#mcalPremium') is span I want to display the result to. It's duplicated in a foreach table, so multiple rows.

Comment: well ids are singular so can't me an id.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So reference the element and use it to find the other input in the same row. It is weird you are only listening to the event on one of the two inputs, but I will follow your way.

```js
$("table").on("input", "td:nth-child(3)", function () {
   var cell = $(this)
   var input1 = +cell.find("input").val() || 0
   var input2 = +cell.parent().find("td:nth-child(2) input").val() || 0
   cell.parent().find("span.result").text(input1+input2)
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>One</td>
    <td><input type="number" value="1"/></td>
    <td><input type="number" value="1"/></td>
    <td><span class="result"></span></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>TWO</td>
    <td><input type="number" value="2"/></td>
    <td><input type="number" value="2"/></td>
    <td><span class="result"></span></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>THREE</td>
    <td><input type="number" value="3"/></td>
    <td><input type="number" value="3"/></td>
    <td><span class="result"></span></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: thanks for the assist. It's really close. I took your example and added the components from mine. I posted a picture of what's happening. I changed the ID to a class capture instead and it changes the td for all rows. If you look at the picture you'll see what I mean. I need to find a way to isolate to just that tr and td

Comment: because you are not selecting the span in the row like I am. You are selecting all the spans

Comment: YOU'RE ABSOLUTELY RIGHT. I missed that cell.parent you added. That was exactly what I needed. Thank you for the help. I learned a lot from doing this.